# Exception thrown at 0x00007FFB3EEB2181 (ucrtbased.dll) - even for a program that works on other compiler ?(Visual studio community version)

Tags: c, visual-studio, scanf, c-strings

I am new to C programming. I have been trying to run this program which run pretty well on the online compiler. I have tried changing the language version for the C language. When I run the program and write a string it prints nothing just stops the program. Then I tried to debug it to see what was wrong and it showed this "Exception thrown at 0x00007FFB3EEB2181 (ucrtbased.dll) in ".
I am using the latest visual studio (community version). I will really appreciate if someone helps me to solve this.
sometimes I even get some useless errors for just one error. ( e.g I forget to put the end bracket, the compiler throws many errors including the end bracket one) is my app is curropted or there is some setting missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    char str[20];
    printf("Enter something\n");

    // Here \n indicates that take the input
    // until newline is encountered
    scanf_s("%[^\n]s", str);
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: scanf_s() is safe in more than one way, it intentionally throws an exception when you don't use it correctly.  It needs to know the size of *str*.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this call of scanf

```
scanf_s("%[^\n]s", str);
```

you need to write

```
scanf_s("%[^\n]", str, ( rsize_t )20 );
```

or

```
scanf_s("%[^\n]", str, ( rsize_t )sizeof( str ) );
```

From the C Standard (K.3.5.3.2 The fscanf_s function)

> 4 **The fscanf_s function is equivalent to fscanf except that the c,
> s, and [ conversion specifiers apply to a pair of arguments** (unless
> assignment suppression is indicated by a *). The first of these
> arguments is the same as for fscanf. That argument is immediately
> followed in the argument list by the second argument, which has type
> rsize_t and gives the number of elements in the array pointed to by
> the first argument of the pair. If the first argument points to a
> scalar object, it is considered to be an array of one element.3

The same is valid for the function `scanf_s`.

Instead of using `scanf_s` you can use `scanf` as for example

```
scanf("%19[^\n]", str);
```

Comment: Wow why it worked? why we have to write addition line? is there any resources to learn?

Comment: @Obiick See my appended answer.

Comment: how to make my compiler in sucha way that could run like the above program( the one that I post, simple one)

Comment: @Obiick You can write for example scanf("%19[^\n]", str);